# What does it take to gain reputation on superuser.com?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation

I've asked a couple of questions.  I've answered a couple.  But my rep is still at 1.  What gives?  I'd like to start commenting and up voting.  And why doesn't rep span all the sites?

Comment: You only have 2 answers and 2 questions. Try answering more questions.

Comment: Yeah I also went to check. Thankfully he said couple that indicates a pair. :)

Answer (score 2):

You gain reputation by having answers accepted and by having your questions upvoted. Looking at your history you've only asked 2 questions and posted 2 answers.

The answers where on Community Wiki posts which is why you have not had any rep gained. However it does take time and hard work.

Click on the Users tab and have a look at the history of the top posters and it would give you an idea how they are able to do it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that there is a mass of questions which are just "What is you favorite" or "must have" questions that have no real answer, and therefore fit under a Community Wiki (and therefore no reputation gain/loss) status.

Once these questions die down and people actually start posting real questions and answers, then more rep is going to start moving.

Comment: I ended up here because of this.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the same thing as it does on the other sites, getting upvotes on non-community wiki questions and/or answers. As for why rep doesn't span all the sites, there's been a few [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336) on here about that you can look at.

Answer (score 0):

Persistence. Dedication. It's been two days and several of us have reached 700-800 points. You've got to go psycho on the system, man :)

Think of things you already know - organizing firefox bookmarks, for example. Ask a question, "How exactly do I better organize my firefox bookmarks?" And then answer your own question. If others like your answer, you'll get up-voted. Maybe they'll up-vote the question itself.

If you know simple questions, ask them, and answer them. Somebody else will eventually come across them and benefit from your efforts.

Comment: You may have 800 rep but I am still above you. For now :)

Comment: Alphabetically! :)

Comment: Lolz - Do you blame me for taking a shot :)

Comment: Hehe. Just wait till my rep-gate opens, I'm going to hit the ground running ;)

Comment: I know and because of the time difference I am going to have to work my backside off again to catch up. The hassle of being in the wrong timezone.

Comment: I guess that would work and is still somewhat useful but I was really just looking to get to the point where i can start commenting and up voting answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you link your Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User accounts on the "accounts" tab on your profile page, you'll get a one-time +100 rep bonus for each link.

Comment: Only if you have more than 200 rep on one of the sites.